# Why is .<name_of_cookie> not accessable using window.document.cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, browser

Some of my cookies are being stored with .name_of_cookie which is not coming up in window.document.cookie.

The cookie is being set by a third party application hosted on same IP/Domain And yes it's an HTTP only cookie.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. How are these cookies being set? How are you trying to read them? Are they marked as httpOnly?

Comment: Any other information would you require? @Quentin Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The point of httpOnly cookies is that **JavaScript cannot read them**. This provides a measure of protection against cookie theft via XSS attacks.